# Sorting by multiple conditions in Google sheet within one row

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to sort a table (that I cannot show for confidentiality reasons) with the following structure:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpGP1.png)

and I'm doing it via apps script

what I'm trying to achieve is that all the data is sorted according to column E which is sorted again in a much complex pattern (the code will show it). I hoped to achieve this by simply setting the numbers in an oderPatterns array because I wanted it to be shown the exact order that I wrote the patterns in I hope that makes sense

- so first 99-97 then 94 then 89-80 and so on following the structure I wrote

the problem is though it just gets sorted in an descending order keeping the 94 ones at the very top no matter what I try

this is the code:

```
function orderByCustomPattern() {
  var sheetName = 'Dev-Test';  // Replace with the name of your sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();


// Custom ordering patterns
  var orderPatterns = [
    { pattern: /^9[0-3]\d/, order: 1 },  // Starts with 9[0-3]x, ascending order
    { pattern: /^94/, order: 2 },        // Starts with 94, order 2
    { pattern: /^8[0-6]\d|^8[7-9]\d|^80/, order: 3 },  // Starts with 8[0-6]x or 8[7-9]x or 80, ascending order
    { pattern: /^6[0-6]\d/, order: 4 },  // Starts with 6[0-6]x, ascending order
    { pattern: /^8[7-9]\d/, order: 5 },  // Starts with 8[7-9]x, ascending order
    { pattern: /^6[7-9]\d/, order: 6 },  // Starts with 6[9-7]x, ascending order
  ];



  // Sort the data based on the custom ordering
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aValue = a[4].toString();  // Column E
    var bValue = b[4].toString();  // Column E

    for (var i = 0; i < orderPatterns.length; i++) {
      var pattern = orderPatterns[i].pattern;
      var order = orderPatterns[i].order;

      if (pattern.test(aValue) && pattern.test(bValue)) {
        // Both values match the pattern, compare order values
        return order - order;
      } else if (pattern.test(aValue)) {
        // Only aValue matches the pattern, aValue comes first
        return -1;
      } else if (pattern.test(bValue)) {
        // Only bValue matches the pattern, bValue comes first
        return 1;
      }
    }

    // No pattern matches, use default comparison
    return aValue.localeCompare(bValue);
  });

  // Write the sorted data back to the sheet
  dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: `that I cannot show for confidentiality reasons` It is never expected that private or confidential data will be supplied. Instead, you create dummy data to take the place of the confidential data. If you choose not to supply _any_ data, then there is a higher likelihood that your question may not be answered.